# Reuse already implemented functions in Java (Swing)

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to implement new function in project which must reuse already implemented functions. I know that I should create an instance to access these functions. However, I completely new in Java and it seems I stuck with that. The project uses the Model View Controller system.

I should reuse multiplication, division and logarithm function to create a new class inside the project.

Basically, there are two textboxes and four buttons in the panel.

[image]

The last button (MDL) created for the new function which represents Multiplication, Division, and Logarithm. The view part seems fine.

I added action listener to this button in Controller:

```
public class Controller {
    public Controller(View view) {
        // begin-user-code
        view.addMultiplyListener(new MultiplyListener(view));
        view.addDivideListener(new DivideListener(view));
        view.addLogarithmListener(new LogarithmListener(view));
        view.addMdlListener(new mdlListener(view));

        // end-user-code
    }
}
```

Normally it should take the value inside the textboxes. Here is the mdlListener.java:

```
public class mdlListener extends Listener {

    public mdlListener(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    @Override
    public Parameters getParameters(View view) {
        Parameters parameters = new Parameters();
        double a = Lib.convertTextToNumber(view.getTextA());
        parameters.put("a", Double.class, a);
        double b = Lib.convertTextToNumber(view.getTextB());
        parameters.put("b", Double.class, b);
        return parameters;
    }

    @Override
    public IMathAlgorithm getAlgorithm(Parameters parameters) {
        return new MDL(parameters);
    }


}
```

It returns some parameters and finally, these parameters used in MDL class to perform the new function which is  (a * b) + (a / b) - log(a) 
Here is the MDL.java:

```
public class MDL extends MathAlgorithm implements IMathAlgorithm {
    private final double a;
    private final double b;

    /** 
     * <!-- begin-UML-doc -->
     * <!-- end-UML-doc -->
     */
    public MDL(Parameters parameters) {
        // begin-user-code
        a = parameters.get("a", Double.class);
        b = parameters.get("b", Double.class);
        // end-user-code
    }


    /** 
     * <!-- begin-UML-doc -->
     * <!-- end-UML-doc -->
     */
    public void run() {
        // begin-user-code
        status = 0;
        result = (a * b) + (a / b) - Math.log(a);
        // end-user-code
    }
}
```

It is working fine. However it must use already implemented functions.

Here is the Multiplication class:

```
public class Multiplication extends MathAlgorithm implements IMathAlgorithm {
    private final double a;
    private final double b;

    /** 
     * <!-- begin-UML-doc -->
     * <!-- end-UML-doc -->
     */
    public Multiplication(Parameters parameters) {
        // begin-user-code
        a = parameters.get("a", Double.class);
        b = parameters.get("b", Double.class);
        // end-user-code
    }


    /** 
     * <!-- begin-UML-doc -->
     * <!-- end-UML-doc -->
     */
    public void run() {
        // begin-user-code
        status = 0;
        result = a * b;
        // end-user-code
    }
}
```

Division and Logarithm are similar to this structure. I hope you get the idea.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You say you know you should "create an instance to access these functions".  And you are correct.  So what, specifically, is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: When I create an instance it gives an error that I should pass parameters inside it. Even when I define parameters the same problem still remains.

Comment: Are you passing the right kinds of parameters?  The `Multiplication` class constructor, for example, takes a single `Parameters` instance as an argument.

Comment: A [mre] code post and full error messages would help